# Hide ToolTip for base Button of Inherited button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a inherited button which I use in a Winform application that uses a tooltip control. All is good with the tooltip, but it appears that the base class button in showing a tooltip along with the parent. I would like to disable the base class button from showing it's tooltip while preserving the tooltip for the parent. I wanted to post the picture showing the dual tooltip, but too much a newbie here.

```css
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GUI
{
    public partial class ToggleButton : Button
    {
        private Button button;

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Gets or sets the botton state")]
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool State { get; set; }

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Gets or sets the TRUE state text")]
        public string TrueText { get; set; }

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Gets or sets the FALSE state text")]
        public string FalseText { get; set; }

        public ToggleButton() : base(){}

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.button.Name = "button";
            this.button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button.Text = "button";
            this.button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            State = !State;
            clickedButton.Text = State ? TrueText : FalseText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will be able to upload images as soon as you gain some reputation. Until then, you should still provide an image describing your issue if you have such an image. Just upload an image somewhere (e.g. [imgur](http://imgur.com/)), edit your question, and then someone will edit your question for you embidding the acutal image to the body of the post.

Comment: This is pretty broken code, the button you create in the constructor is not visible and its Click event never fired.  Where the tooltip might come from requires blind guessing.  Clearly you ought to make a fresh start, this time use a CheckBox as the base class.